# best way to get user data using single-sign-on

Tags: architecture, single-sign-on, onelogin

I have the following problem and I can not find a better solution.
I have an SSO server and a REST client application.

1. 1 - The client logs in to the SSO that returns a token and the id of
   the user "user_id"
2. 2 - The application saves this data (token, user_id) in a table
   (user_table) of the database.
3. 3 - The client application needs to list all users and their
   information (name, age, address, etc.) but this information is in
   SSO.

What is the best way to get this user information?

I thought about making each user a SSO request by passing the token and user_id, or when the client logs in, that user information is saved in the user_table table.

But if the user updates some information using another client application? How can I upgrade on all client applications?

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches to solve this and at the end depends on your app final desired behavior.

1. Real-time sync.
2. Just-in-time provisioning/updating when SSO.

Case 1.

Some Identity Management systems, like OneLogin, are able to execute hooks when user data is changed in its system. So for example, if a user updates its email, you can set up a hook that will execute a call to final app API in order to update user account on final app.

In the same way, sometimes is interesting that users can edit its profile in final app, and apply that change on IdM system, for that you can use the IdM API , so when user edit its profile on final app, it executes an API call to the IdM API.
(notice that if the idM system is configured with hooks on final apps, those hooks will be executed on IdM system so final apps will be automatically updated too).

Case 2.

When the user executes a SSO process (SAML/OIDC, JIT), its data can be provided from IdM system to final app, at that moment, final app can use the data provided to sync it.
Cons. If a user doesn't execute a SSO, the account is not created/updated.

Case 1 makes sense in environments where having updated user data is critical, like for example, a LMS where the teacher needs to know the set of students of his classroom, but if you rely on SSO process (SAML/OIDC, JIT) to create/update student account, if the student never access the LMS, the teacher never knows that the student exists.

Answer (score 1):

Most SSO's have their own API that you can query against and you would have to do that as the data would only exist there.  Like Onelogin, which you tagged has a user API that you could have your app query if it had API access.

You could also store this data in one of the client applications and use SSO from the other apps to control access to that data.  This would leave your SSO for control of access and your clients to manage the non access control data.